Boxes to expression
I have defined MakeExpression as below and I could convert boxes to my expression. But I couldn't get the expected expression, if I attach "-1" or "-"  in front of boxes. Could I know how to fix my code?

MakeExpression[RowBox[{SubsuperscriptBox["S", xmin_, xmax_], terms_}],
   StandardForm] := 
 MakeExpression[
  RowBox[{"my", "[", terms, ",", "{", xmin, ",", xmax, "}", "]"}], 
  StandardForm]

\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(S\), \(a\), \(b\)] \(\({x, y}\)\(.\)\({d1, 
   d2}\)\(\ \ \)\( (*boxes\ to\ expression\ ok*) \)\)\)


\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(S\), \(a\), \(b\)]\) {x, y} . {d1, 
   d2}   (*How to get "-my[d1 x+d2 y,{a,b}]" ?*)


You'll need to handle two cases: One where there are additional terms before the $S_a^b$, and one where there is a unary minus attached to it. You can look at the box form ("Show cell expression" in the cells context menu) to see how the boxes for the problematic cases look exactly

You could use parentheses to group the S operator and its argument. You're fighting the precedence that the Front End applies in parsing input into boxes. Alternatively, consider using a built-in operator to aid the parsing. For instance SubsuperscriptBox["S", xmin_, xmax_] \[Colon] terms_. The precendence of Colon[] seems to work, and it's kind of natural looking.
